# Flutter how to add a tabbarview using SliverToBoxAdapter?

Tags: flutter

i trying to use tabbarview to see a new bar on my application, but nothing im trying worked, someone can help me?

this is my code:

```
SliverToBoxAdapter _buildRegionTabBar() { //brasil e mundo
    return SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
          height: 50.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white24,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
          ),
          child: TabBar(
            indicator: BubbleTabIndicator(
              tabBarIndicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
              indicatorHeight: 40.0,
              indicatorColor: Colors.white,
            ),
            labelStyle: Styles.tabTextStyle,
            labelColor: Colors.black,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Tab (text:'Brasil'),
              Tab (text:'Mundo'),
            ],
            onTap: (index) {},
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: use container with height and column child and use Expanded for tabbar view, if your tabbar view its not in DefaultTabController children you must use tabbar and tabbar controller instead DefaultTabController ,and finally  its better use tabbar in sliverappbar see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html

Comment: can you show me the code? I could not understand

Answer (score 0):

```
class ExampleTabbar extends StatelessWidget {
  const ExampleTabbar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: NestedScrollView(
              key: PageStorageKey<String>('keepTabScroll'),
              headerSliverBuilder: (context, _) {
                return [
                  SliverOverlapAbsorber(
                    handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(
                        context),
                    sliver: SliverAppBar(
                      title: Text("Tabbar"),
                      forceElevated: _,
                      bottom: TabBar(tabs: [
                        Tab(
                          text: 'Tab A',
                        ),
                        Tab(
                          text: 'Tab B',
                        ),
                      ]),
                    ),
                  )
                ];
              },
              body: TabBarView(
                children: [
                  TabA(),
                  TabB(),
                ],
              ))),
    );
  }
}

class TabA extends StatelessWidget {
  const TabA({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverOverlapInjector(
            handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context)),
        SliverPadding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24, horizontal: 16),
          sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Text("Tab A"),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class TabB extends StatelessWidget {
  const TabB({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverOverlapInjector(
            handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context)),
        SliverPadding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24, horizontal: 16),
          sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Text("Tab B"),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```